# How can I submit my form when clicking on go button in Ionic 3 framework?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

In my Ionic 3 application, I want to submit a form when I click on the **go button** from my mobile keyboard.

I want to trigger an event or call a function when I click on the **go button** on my mobile keyboard.

Comment: @sebaferreras discuss very good. If you don't understand then update your code then i try to resolve it.......

Comment: I'm sorry @Utpaul but I didn't understand your comment... What happens with the code in my answer?

Comment: @sebaferreras you discuss briefly and i said that Mr. GAURAV implements any code for solving this purpose , if he got any problem in code i will resolve it..

Answer (score 1):

```
Here is the solution 
**code for HTML file**

    enter code here

    <form (ngSubmit)="onUserLogin()" [formGroup]="myForm">
    <ion-item no-padding transparent>
    <ion-label floating>{{data.username}}</ion-label>
    <ion-input required type="text" [(ngModel)]="username" formControlName="text" autocapitalize='off'></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <!---Input field password-->
    <ion-item no-padding transparent>
    <!--<ion-icon name="lock"></ion-icon>-->
    <ion-label floating>{{data.password}}</ion-label>
    <ion-input required type="password" [(ngModel)]="password" formControlName="password"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>

    <!-- Remember me check box -->
    <ion-item no-padding transparent no-lines>
    <ion-label class="rememberme">{{data.remember}}</ion-label>
    <ion-toggle [(ngModel)]="checkbox" formControlName="checkbox" ></ion-toggle>
    </ion-item>
    <button [disabled]="!myForm.valid" type="submit" style="visibility: hidden;width: 1px;height: 1px;padding: 0;margin: 0;"></button>
    </form>

**code for ts file**

    enter code here
import {Validators, FormBuilder, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

    @IonicPage()
    @Component({
      selector: 'page-login',
      templateUrl: 'login.html',
    })

export class LoginPage {
  private myForm : FormGroup;

  constructor(
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    public platform: Platform,
) {
    this.myForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      text: [''],
      password: [''],
      checkbox: ['']
    });

onUserLogin = function () {
//Enter your code 
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to do that, you'd need to add a `button` of type `submit` **inside** of your form, and handle the submit event.

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-navbar>
        <ion-title>My Form</ion-title>
    </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content padding>
    <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" [formGroup]="myForm">

        <ion-list>
            <ion-item>
                <ion-label stacked>Email</ion-label>
                <ion-input formControlName="email" type="email"></ion-input>
            </ion-item>
            <ion-item>
                <ion-label stacked>Password</ion-label>
                <ion-input formControlName="password" type="password"></ion-input>
            </ion-item>
        </ion-list>

        <!-- The button should be inside of the form -->
        <button type="submit">Login</button>

    </form>
</ion-content>
```

Please notice this line:

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" [formGroup]="myForm">
```

where basically we tell Angular to execute the `onSubmit()` method when the user taps on that button or in the *GO* button from the keyboard.

```
public onSubmit(): void {
  // ...
  // ...
}
```

---

If for some reason (based on the UI/UX of your app) you need to put that button **outside** of the `form` element, you could use the following trick: Add a hidden button inside of the form, with the type `submit`.

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-navbar>
        <ion-title>My Form</ion-title>
    </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content padding>
    <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" [formGroup]="myForm">
        <ion-list>    
            <ion-item>
                <ion-label stacked>Email</ion-label>
                <ion-input formControlName="email" type="email"></ion-input>
            </ion-item>    
            <ion-item>
                <ion-label stacked>Password</ion-label>
                <ion-input formControlName="password" type="password"></ion-input>
            </ion-item>    
        </ion-list>

        <!-- 
            Hidden button to make the GO button submit the form, 
            since the button is in the footer (outside the form tag) 
        -->
        <button type="submit" style="visibility: hidden;width: 1px;height: 1px;padding: 0;margin: 0;"></button>

    </form>
</ion-content>
<ion-footer no-border>
    <ion-toolbar>
        <button (tap)="onSubmit()" ion-button block text-only>
            Login
        </button>
    </ion-toolbar>
</ion-footer>
```

So now user will use the button in the footer, but the hidden button will allow your users to submit the form when using the *GO* button from the keyboard.

Comment: Thanks @sebaferreras, your code really help me to get the solution

Answer (score 0):

No need of a complicated button type, a simple button is enough, you just have to wrap up all your inputs and your button inside  tags.

Answer (score 0):

You should add this tag between `<form>`:

```
<input type="submit" hidden>
```